# Booting a "hidden" installation by a combination of keys

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios

Is there anyway to boot a installation on a computer by pressing some combination of keys? I know you can select the boot media in bios, but I wan't to be able to boot my installation by pressing a combination of keys during startup.

Lets say I have windows 10 installed on a partition on the HDD, the computer automatically boots from this partition since it's the first in the boot order settings in the bios. Could I press "ctrl + shift + P" to boot another partition with a linux installation? What necessary changes would I need to make for this to be done.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Basiclly I want to boot a partition by pressing "CTRL + Shift + P" during boot. If this combination is not pressed, the computer boots the first partition in the boot order.

Comment: Please read the link I've provided. I understand what you're asking. My question is _why_? What's the goal behind this?

Comment: On a computer there is BIOS boot option right? most devices have this by pressing F9 during startup, when you press this button you will get a list of boot options  like : 1) boot from ssd XXX1, 2) boot from SATA HDD XXXX2  and so on..
What i want to do is skip this menu by pressing some other key during startup to boot the select option "2".

Comment: I understand and I ask _why_? What is the goal you're trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: So the goal would be to have a "hidden" installation of an OS. That is hidden to the naked eye if you will. The hidden OS will be my main OS and primary boot as the guest OS.  A scenario is, your Girlfriend wants to go through your computer, I don't want do show her everything i have on my computer. I will boot the computer to the "guest OS" which is the primary one in the boot order (not pressing any keys during boot) without risking that she will find anything. This scenario is just for the sake of argument..

Comment: And the shortcut is just a convenience feature over selecting the other OS from boot menu? I don't think that's possible. But anyway, this won't fool more competent people. You could consider disk encryption with plausible deniability, Veracrypt can do that.